# How to only allow alphabets and spaces in the middle in Profile2 field

Tags: 7, forms, users

I'd like to only allow alphabets in and spaces in the middle of a my Profile2 "real_Name" field. I have found what I think I need: [profile2_form_validate_handler](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_form_validate_handler/7) but I don't know how to get it to work.

I think it should be similar to [user_validate_name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_validate_name/7), especially for

```
  if (!$name) {
  if (substr($name, 0, 1) == ' ')
  if (substr($name, -1) == ' ')
  if (strpos($name, '  ') !== FALSE)
```

and I should use

```
preg_match('/[^A-Za-z ]/'
```

I only have a rough idea but I don't know how to make it work and I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Profile2 module simply adds a new profile2 entity. It still uses the Field API for the individual fields. I'd create a custom module with a new field type for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) So how should I do that? I've never done that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the [Field validation](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module that works! I used this regex expression:

```
^[\x{00c0}-\x{01ff}a-zA-Z0-9]+([- '][\x{00c0}-\x{01ff}a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

This way I can allow international names and only allow spaces, hyphens and apostrophes in the middle of the name.

It was based on combining

1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275160/regex-for-names , and 
2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525327/regex-for-a-za-z0-9-with-dashes-allowed-in-between-but-not-at-the-start-or-e